# Regra de validação ignorada

Tags: laravel-5, validação

Saudações,

Estou com dificuldades em fazer uma validação pelo Laravel.  Hoje, preciso fazer a seguinte validação

```
'data_visita'  => ['required', 'date_format:d/m/Y', new AfterOrEqual1900],
```

quando está somente `['required', 'date_format:d/m/Y']` o sistema tenta a validação normalmente, verifica se é obrigatório e se está no formato especificado. Porém, quando acrescento a validação `new AfterOrEqual1900` a segunda validação, `'date_format:d/m/Y'` é ignorada e passa direto para o última. Alguém pode me informar o que acontece?

A regra AfterOrEqual1900 é,

De qualquer forma, o código para AfterOrEqual1900 é,

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
  $timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
  $min_date = Carbon::create(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, $timezone);
  $date_of_visit = new Carbon(Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value, $timezone));

  // importante zerar para comparação sair corretamente
  $date_of_visit->second = 0;
  $date_of_visit->minute = 0;
  $date_of_visit->hour = 0;

  return $date_of_visit->gte($min_date);
}
```

Comment: me explica o que você quer validar nessa validação

Comment: Preciso verificar se a data é anterior a 01/01/1900. Então, verifico se foi passado um valor, se a data está nesse formato dd/mm/yyyy e, por último, como não encontrei outra forma de se comparar, criei uma regra personalizada.

Comment: `AfterOrEqual1900` coloca esse método na pergunta para eu analisar, como ele que esta sendo ignorado, pode ser a lógica dele o problema.

Comment: O método `AfterOrEqual1900` não é ignorado. O problema é que ele é analisado, antes do `'date_format:d/m/Y'`.

Comment: se você deixar apenas essa validação `AfterOrEqual1900` ela se comporta como deveria ?

Comment: Acho que isso aqui pode esclarecer algumas coisas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692792/how-validation-rules-work-in-laravel

Comment: Agora entendi o que estava errado. O Laravel faz as validações sem usar a avaliação short-circuit, ou seja, ele vai verificar todas as regras, antes de retornar, independente se ocorreu um erro ou não. Para forçar o comportamento short-circuit é necessário prefixar com `bail` as regras de validação. Agradeço pela força.

Answer (score 0):

Eu prefiro utilizar o rules em uma array, exemplo:

```
rules = [
   'data_visita'        => 'required|date|date_format:d/m/Y|after_or_equal:1990'
];
```

Porém, creio que assim deva funcionar:

```
'data_visita'  => ['required', 'date', 'date_format:d/m/Y', 'after_or_equal:1990']
```